# Fetching Data when push notification arrives Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

So when the app is not running or in background, i want to fetch the received Message(push) and save it in local data store so when the user opens the app they can see the messages instead

I tried this but its not getting called

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        //fetch Data and save in local datastore here.
    }
```

Comment: When your app is not running, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **Silent Notifications**:

Silent notifications are not meant as a way to keep your app awake in the background beyond quick refresh operations, nor are they meant for high priority updates. APNs treats background update notifications as low priority and may throttle their delivery altogether if the total number becomes excessive. The actual limits are dynamic and can change based on conditions, but try not to send more than a few notifications per hour.

Silent notification payload should be like this :

```
{
    "aps" = {
        "content-available" : 1,
        "sound" : ""
    };
    // You can add custom key-value pair here...
}
```

> When a silent notification arrives, iOS wakes up your app in the
>   background so that you can get new data from your server or do
>   background information processing.
>
> For a silent notification, take care to ensure there is no alert,
>   sound, or badge payload in the aps dictionary.

You can follow this link: https://medium.com/@m.imadali10/ios-silent-push-notifications-84009d57794c

Add below keys in your plist file for Transport security:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: but can i fetch the data from server? how does whatsapp works?

Comment: @TestDjay: Yes, You can fetch data from server

Comment: silent notification won't show the push notification, right? i need to show push and fetch the message from server to save in localdatastore

Comment: You can change "content-available"  then you can show your notifications. And also allow background fetch from capabilities

Comment: So there's a notification on the user's screen when we do `"content-available" : 0` plus the alert dict, and there's none, but the app still receives it when we put `"content-available" : 1` w/o the alert dict?

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary this seems to be working, but i am trying to fetch data and it gives me HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89]) .... (PS. Allow Arbitrary Loads is YES) , any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: @TestDjay: you have to check transport security in plist. Please check my updated answer

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary yes its true, thats what i said "(PS. Allow Arbitrary Loads is YES)"

Comment: Can you check this loads to "No"

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary app stops working if i set to "No"

Comment: I have updated my answer again, Please check with that and if not working then please add your base URL in that domain for your loads

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary that is exactly what I'm using

Comment: replace example.com with your base url